# Add signature require on shipping

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-community, magento-ce

I want to know does magento provide signature require for shipping.Like when customer receives their order they need to sign the shipment.My shipping method is UPS.So is there any way to configure UPS in magento for this purpose?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: following link for magento2 may be helpful some one get into this place..https://github.com/sivajik34/Delivery-Signature-Magento2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not native functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box no. However you can always use an add-on shipping module from Magento Connect that will fully integrate with USPS.

[See USPS Compatible Shipping Modules Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=usps&pl=0)

You should also request that USPS ensure that all your shipments include a signature for delivery.